# cannot create list in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a webpage with parallax scrolling using skrollr, but when I copied an unordered list (which worked in another page with no skrollr included) into the parallax webpage, they appear with the words only (no ordered numbers, or unordered dots) as well as being un-clickable for the link, when I remove the script line:

```
<script src="dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
```

The links became clickable, but the list still had no `list-style`; I tried to set `z-index` to `1000`, but didn't work.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
p,
a,
del,
em,
img,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
html,
body {
  line-height: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: Artial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
q {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #333;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.91em;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 > small {
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: .71em;
  text-indent: 15em;
  color: #444;
}
h2 {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 1.91em;
  margin: 2em 0 1em 0;
}
h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
h3 {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.41em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
#progress {
  height: 2%;
  background: #444;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 200;
}
#scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  z-index: 300;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.skrollr-desktop #scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#bg1,
#bg2,
#bg3 {
  z-index: 50;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(images/bubbles.png) repeat 0 0;
}
#bg2 {
  z-index: 49;
  background-image: url(images/bubbles2.png);
}
#bg3 {
  z-index: 48;
  background-image: url(images/bubbles3.png);
}
#page1 {
  float: left;
  color: #F03;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 80%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 1em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 2em;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page3 {
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
#page4 {
  color: #033;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#easing_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#easing {
  top: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 101;
}
.drop {
  background: #09f;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1em;
}
#download {
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 3em;
  border: 0 solid #222;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.twitter-share-button,
.twitter-follow-button {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
Các giai đoạn chính của Tết gồm :
<ul style="text-decoration:none; text-align:left">
  <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Cu.E1.BB.91i_n.C4.83m">Cuối năm</li>
<li>Tất niên
 <ol>
     <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Giao_th.E1.BB.ABa">Giao thừa</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#C.C3.BAng_Giao_th.E1.BB.ABa_ngo.C3.A0i_tr.E1.BB.9Di">Cúng giao thừa ngoài trời</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#C.C3.BAng_Giao_th.E1.BB.ABa_trong_nh.C3.A0">Cúng giao thừa trong nhà</a>
  </li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Bảy ngày đầu năm</li>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Ba_ng.C3.A0y_T.C3.A2n_ni.C3.AAn">Ba ngày tân niên</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#X.C3.B4ng_.C4.91.E1.BA.A5t">Xông đất</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Xu.E1.BA.A5t_h.C3.A0nh_v.C3.A0_h.C3.A1i_l.E1.BB.99c">Xuất hành và hái lộc</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Ch.C3.BAc_T.E1.BA.BFt">Chúc Tết</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#T.E1.BB.A5c_th.C4.83m_vi.E1.BA.BFng">Tục thăm viếng</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#M.E1.BB.ABng_tu.E1.BB.95i">Mừng tuổi</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#H.C3.B3a_v.C3.A0ng">Hóa vàng</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Khai_h.E1.BA.A1">Khai hạ</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: your css is specifying not to display anything: `ol, ul { list-style:none; }` - remove this and you should be good to go - Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: I tried, but it seems doens't makes changes, even when i add ul {list-style: circle)

Comment: ok, the margin was a culprit too - good to know you got an answer

Comment: Yeah, tks bro ^^
it's all done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS explicitly sets `margin` to `0` and `list-style` to `none`.

If you specify a `margin-left` property or greater than zero, and remove the `list-style` CSS then everything should work:

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
p,
a,
del,
em,
img,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
html,
body {
  line-height: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: Artial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
/*
Removing the list-style rules:
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
*/
q {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #333;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.91em;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 > small {
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: .71em;
  text-indent: 15em;
  color: #444;
}
h2 {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 1.91em;
  margin: 2em 0 1em 0;
}
h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
h3 {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.41em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
#progress {
  height: 2%;
  background: #444;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 200;
}
#scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  z-index: 300;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.skrollr-desktop #scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#bg1,
#bg2,
#bg3 {
  z-index: 50;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(images/bubbles.png) repeat 0 0;
}
#bg2 {
  z-index: 49;
  background-image: url(images/bubbles2.png);
}
#bg3 {
  z-index: 48;
  background-image: url(images/bubbles3.png);
}
#page1 {
  float: left;
  color: #F03;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 80%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 1em;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 2em;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  padding-top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page3 {
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: 250px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
#page4 {
  color: #033;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#easing_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#easing {
  top: 10%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 101;
}
.drop {
  background: #09f;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1em;
}
#download {
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 3em;
  border: 0 solid #222;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.twitter-share-button,
.twitter-follow-button {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* adding a margin-left for the <li> elements: */
li {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
Các giai đoạn chính của Tết gồm :
<ul style="text-decoration:none; text-align:left">
  <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Cu.E1.BB.91i_n.C4.83m">Cuối năm</li>
<li>Tất niên
 <ol>
     <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Giao_th.E1.BB.ABa">Giao thừa</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#C.C3.BAng_Giao_th.E1.BB.ABa_ngo.C3.A0i_tr.E1.BB.9Di">Cúng giao thừa ngoài trời</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#C.C3.BAng_Giao_th.E1.BB.ABa_trong_nh.C3.A0">Cúng giao thừa trong nhà</a>
  </li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Bảy ngày đầu năm</li>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Ba_ng.C3.A0y_T.C3.A2n_ni.C3.AAn">Ba ngày tân niên</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#X.C3.B4ng_.C4.91.E1.BA.A5t">Xông đất</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Xu.E1.BA.A5t_h.C3.A0nh_v.C3.A0_h.C3.A1i_l.E1.BB.99c">Xuất hành và hái lộc</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Ch.C3.BAc_T.E1.BA.BFt">Chúc Tết</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#T.E1.BB.A5c_th.C4.83m_vi.E1.BA.BFng">Tục thăm viếng</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#M.E1.BB.ABng_tu.E1.BB.95i">Mừng tuổi</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#H.C3.B3a_v.C3.A0ng">Hóa vàng</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E1%BA%BFt_Nguy%C3%AAn_%C4%90%C3%A1n#Khai_h.E1.BA.A1">Khai hạ</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tks bro,i tried remove list-style only, but adding margin solved :D